# How to download video from facebook comment using yt-dlp using python?

Tags: python, video, facebook-comments, yt-dlp

I am trying to download a public video posted in comment replying to another video post using `yt-dlp`. I opened the commented video by right clicking on date and opening it in new fb tab. Here is my code but it downloads the posted video not the comment video:

```
import yt_dlp
ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': 'videos/%(extractor)s/%(title)s [%(resolution)s] [%(id)s].%(ext)s'}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    yvd=ydl.download(['https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid0uexSewpRL4h2bbSRkfdzoLwtAYB2pLuwZAh7a2GEmHK9FDp2J4mLGxiANzHpMDhWl&id=100030938700245&comment_id=486910773264306'])

print("")
print(yvd)
```

How can I get the correct url of fb comment video to download it using yt-dlp in python?

Comment: Have you considered using [`pyfacebook`](https://pypi.org/project/python-facebook-api/) and the [comment endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment)?